# What's the grammar behind "A'warring", from the lyrics of Symphony of Destruction?

Tags: apostrophe

What's the grammar behind `A'warring`, from the lyrics of Symphony of Destruction by Megadeth?

It's the first time I'm seeing the use of such apostrophe.

Comment: The appearance of an /a/ in front of a verb+ing usually means an ongoing or iterative form of the verb's action. It is a common aspect marking in some dialects of English. It used to be far more common than it is now. As far as orthography goes, that has never been properly settled - [Frog went acourtin'](https://www.loc.gov/item/afc9999005.9372). [A prefixing - Yale Grammar](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/a-prefixing)

Comment: https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/megadeth/symphonyofdestruction.html

Comment: I'll note that music lyrics are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The a- prefix to gerunds or participles of verbs (of motion, in particular), often as an intensifier, is rather old-fashioned or archaic in British English, but still common in certain regional US dialects. An apostrophe can be used in place of a dash.

[A-prefixing](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/a-prefixing)